# CKEditor loads every time when a postback occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

CKEditor loads every time when I submit the form with a button click. I do not want to loads ckeditor every time when page load. The following code is used in f1.aspx

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="test"  BasePath="/editor/" ></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor is just HTML and JS so unless your pageloads happen in a separate contexts different from the editor, such as separate iframes, that is not possible - it will always reload during page reloads.

What is the problem with CKE reloading though? It should be very fast after the first load when most of the assets it loads is cached. If it is an issue, you need to refactor your application to not use callbacks in the parts that annoy you :)

Comment: how can i refactor my application to not use callbacks

Comment: Mostly just replace whatever you do with postbacks with ajax. It depends a lot on what you do with your application and what you can do. If for example the callback is about saving a page that is being edited, replace the postback with an ajax call. So, just replace asp.net tags with regular HTML and JavaScript, then create a backend service you can call with ajax that handles your request and backend stuff. Then instead of a postback, call the service instead and update the view manually. That's really the only way I know.